# Overlap of state subspaces in QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, probability

In many-body QM we are rarely able to solve exactly for (some or all of) the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian. In some fields of condensed matter physics there has been a successful "business" of coming up with trial wave functions that has sane physical properties, that often describe the actual ground state or low-lying states of $H$ with remarkable accuracy.

To measure the degree of agreement between the actual ground state $| \psi \rangle$ and a trial state $| \phi \rangle$ we use the overlap:

$$ O(\psi, \phi) = \frac{|\langle \psi | \phi \rangle|^2}{\langle \psi | \psi \rangle \langle \phi | \phi \rangle} $$

**QUESTION: Is there a way to generalize this notion of overlap to sets of states?**

Let us say that I'm able to come up with a recipe that gives me not one, but a few trial states, and I want to check how well they describe the few lowest-energy exact eigenstates of $H$. Is there a quantity that naturally extends the overlap as defined above? Maybe a quantity derived from the overlap matrix with elements

$$ S_{i,j} = O(\psi_i, \phi_j)~?$$

Comment: So my first instinct is to take the minimum of $O$ over the elements in your set. This feels like cheating however as what you have done in practice hear is reduce your set of elements down to a single element (or at least a much smaller set). I guess what this tells us is that what constitutes a good generalization depends on how much we know about your set of candidates

Comment: What is your notion of "naturally extends" here? If you're looking for something that approximates something like "best fit", looking at the sum of the squared $O$ as in many other fit methods would seem natural, but if you're looking for something else, it might not be...

Comment: @Jakob, thanks! If I have e.g. 4 exact low-lying states and 4 trial states, how would I create one density matrix for the exact, and one for the trials? Fidelity seems interesting since it simplifies to the overlap for pure states!

Comment: @BySymmetry I would say that I "typically" have a situation where the overlap between ground state and the trial state for it is large (>0.95) but the low-lying excited states are not as good. But I would still like to differentiate whether I have e.g. (0.99, 0.8, 0.8) vs. a worse case of (0.99, 0.1, 0.1). Hence my question :)

Comment: @ACuriousMind I am not picky here, hehe! Any quantity that I can use to summarize "how good" my trial state recipe works is all that is required. In the case of sum of squared overlaps, does it make sense to normalize this by dividing by the number of states then? To get something that does not scale with the size of the subspace...

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Sorry, I think I have misunderstood your question.